# can I build python in unix if i'm not a system administrator?

Tags: python, unix

Is it possible build python in my assigned directory on a Unix machine that I SSH to? Since this is a work server, do I need to make this aware to the system administrator if I want to try this. I want to use python instead of perl for advanced text manipulation.

Comment: 1. Yes. 2. How can we possibly know what your administrator cares about?

Comment: Are you sure you don't already have Python?

Comment: @Wooble well, as long as the user has an account on the box and can write to its home directory, building and installing Python into the home directory do not require any privileged operations. One can also build it on another machine and just scp/rsync it.

Comment: @user2357112 Surprisingly there's no python on the AIX server i'm connecting to. I made sure of that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that following [Python building instructions](http://docs.python.org/devguide/setup.html). They are pretty standard configure/make/make-install invocations. Just make sure to pass `--prefix=~/local` to `configure` script, so that it installs into your home directory because you probably don't have rights to install in `/usr/local`. You may need to ask your sysadmin to install extra development packages though, without them python or some python modules may fail to build.

If you can not get the required development packages installed on your server, another option is to build it on your own desktop, where you can install all required development packages, probably in a virtual machine matching the OS of the target box, and then just rsync/scp the directory where you installed it to the same directory on the target machine.

Yet another option is to find a privilege escalation exploit for your kernel, become local `root` and do whatever you want, but this is likely to get you in trouble. From a pure technical perspective though, it could be doable provided you are so determined to manipulate strings with Python.